# PHPMailer using gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail

I'm trying to send emails using PHPMailer and Gmail. It worked fine on PHP 5.5 but when I updated to php 5.6 I get this error (tls on port 587): stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

If I try using ssl on port 465 I get this instead: 2015-05-29 15:11:58  SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2015-05-29 15:11:58    SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

I googled around and the only thing I found out is that I should set up OAUTH2 but I don't know how. I googled around for that as well and found this: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2

I followed that and got stuck when they said that I should update get_auth_token.php. I can't find this file anywhere. This is how I installed phpmailer using composer: "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2"

Do anyone know how to get it working with or without OAUTH2? I'm using php 5.6.8

Thanks in advance,
Busarna4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP 5.6 introduces `SSL` certificate verification, So if your config is broken, it will fail with this **SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed** error. You should fix your SSL, but you can revert to the old behavior by overriding `PHP MAILER` and passing these options to the `smtpConnect` function like this way.

```
$options = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

**@Courtesy** Synchro

Comment: This worked great :) I'll use this as long as I'm running locally and fix the SSL when I go live. Thanks!